# Selection by Location with Have their center in - GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, select-by-location, centroids

I have two polygon GeoDataFrames. I have read them in with the following:

```
import geopandas as gpd
poly1_path = r”.\Input\poly1.shp”
poly2_path = r”.\Input\poly2.shp”
poly1 = gpd.read_file(poly1_path)
poly2 = gpd.read_file(poly2_path)
```

subset = gpd.sjoin ???

I have to create with GeoPandas a similar code to what the "Select by location" with “Have their center in” tool does. So - I want to select features from poly2 that have centers within the poly1.
Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df1 = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/poly1.shp")
ax = df1.boundary.plot(figsize=(20,20), color="green", linewidth=5)

df2 = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/poly2.shp")
df2.plot(ax=ax, color="gray", alpha=0.2)

#Create a point geometry column in df2
df2["point"] = df2.geometry.representative_point() #You can also use .centroid() but they can be outside the polygon.
df2["oldgeom"] = df2.geometry #Save the polygon geometry
df2 = df2.set_geometry("point") #Set the point column as geometry

#Inner join df1 to df2 if df2 point is inside df1 polygon
df3 = gpd.sjoin(left_df=df2, right_df=df1, how="inner")

#Set the geometry back to the original polygon
df3 = df3.set_geometry("oldgeom").drop(columns="geometry").rename_geometry("geometry")
df3.boundary.plot(ax=ax, color="blue", linewidth=2)
```

green=df1, df2=gray, join result (df3)=blue

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works!